# How to set ComboBoxItem properties when using ItemsSource and template bindings?

Tags: wpf, combobox

When I created combobox manually it was no problem, but since the combobox is now populated automatically thanks to setting `ItemsSource` I don't know how to set the properties of each `ComboBoxItem`. Currently I need to set `Selected` action for each item (one global value) and `Tag` (different value per each item).

Currently I only define how the combobox item looks like:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Modules}"
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding ObjectData.ImageSource}" />
             <Label Content="{Binding ObjectData.Label}"/>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```

How to set the properties I mentioned? **Note**: those properties are of `ComboBoxItem`.

`Modules` is the property of my window class:

```
public ObservableCollection<SelectableObject<Module>> Modules { get; private set; }
```

Comment: The collection binded to your ItemsSource must contain those properties. Can you edit your code with the class of whose objects the collection is made.

Comment: @Akansha, thank you, I updated the question. You mean I have to have `Selected` and `Tag` property in each item? Ok, this is doable. But how do I bind them with template?

Comment: you need to have two properties that consists of the object for tag and Selected. You need to place these properties in your Module class

Comment: @Akansha, ok, how do I bind them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ComboBoxItem properties in the `ItemContainerStyle` of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding TagValue}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

When the "global" `Selected` property is not in the item view model, you'll have set the binding source explicitly, e.g. by `RelativeSource/FindAncestor`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!